# Exception Thrown by CrudRepository save method

Tags: exception, spring-boot, save, constraints, crud

I am using CrudRepository save method to persist Profile Object in my Spring boot project as below:

**MyService2.java**:

```
public Profile getProfile(String profileId, String email){
    Profile profile = null;
    MyClass myObj=new MyClass();
    Profile profile = new Profile(profileId, email);
    return myRepository.save(profile);;
}
```

**MyService1.java:**

```
public Profile getProfile(String profileId, String email){
    try{
        return myService2.getProfile(profileId,email);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    {
        throw new MyCustomException(errorMessage, errorCode);
    }

}
```

**MyRepository.java**

```
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Profile, String> {

 ........
}
```

**Profile.java:**

```
@Entity
public class Profile extends BaseDomain {
   @Id
   private String id;
   private String username;

   public Profile() {
    //this is no argument constructor
   }

   public Profile(final String id,final String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username= email;
   }

   //Getter and Setter
 }
```

In Profile object profileId is primaryKey and  unique constraint is applied email field in Database table.

[image: Unique constraint in DB]

getProfile method is getting called from another Service MyService1 class and that service class method is being called from controller.

Now Issue what i am facing is even if i am passing a emailId in the method which is already available in the Database, profile object is being created and no exception is being caught in MyService1. Constraint violation Exception is only being caught in Controller where we are using created profile object further.

Exception message in controller is as follows:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

StackTrace is as below:

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278), org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244), org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521), org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761), org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730), org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:483), org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:290), org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179), org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179), org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213), com.sun.proxy.$Proxy147.createProfile(Unknown Source), com.cp.controllers.api.MyController.createAccount(MyController.java:827), com.cp.controllers.api.MyController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5cafd35f.invoke(), org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204), org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157), org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179), org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179), org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92), org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179), org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655), com.cp.controllers.api.MyController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e2efb29.createAccount(), sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method), sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62), sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498), org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221), org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136), org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114), org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827), org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738), org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85), org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963), org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897), org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970), org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648), org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165), org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165), org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208), org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177), org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346), org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165), org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99), org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165), org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87), org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165), org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77), org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165), org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197), org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108), org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140), org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87), org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349), org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110), org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66), org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785), org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425), org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617), org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

When i pass profileId as null in getProfile method, then Exception is successfully being caught in MyService1 catch block.

Can anybody please explain me this behavior of CrudRepository Save method.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a `@UniqueConstraint` annotation on emailId. How did you specify that this column should be unique.
Did you verify that the column is unique? Could you post the output of the `Describe` (or equivalent for the database you use) command for this table?

Comment: The stacktrace of the exception that is caught in your controller is still missing

Comment: UniqueConstraint is applied in database not in Profile class. Actual coulmn name is username and email that i am passing is getting assigned to username. I have attached screenshot, will generate the exception and share the stacktrace.

Comment: @YannicKlem updated the stack trace that i am getting in controller.

Comment: Hm, looks like your controller calls a method `createProfile()` on a bean and this method throws the exception.

Comment: @YannicKlem right but bean's catch block is not getting executed that was the question actually.First bean's catch block should executed then only it can be thrown back to Controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160282/discussion-between-yannic-klem-and-manish).

Comment: No. In you question you stated that your controller (code isnt provided) calls MyService1.getProfile (not createProfile), which calls MyService2.getProfile (also not createProfile). Provide a running example on github and i will have a look at this. Not willing to ask you for relevant code even more which is obviously not the real code but something you think does the same.